# 3D Graph (Parameters Changing)

Tags: 3d, math-software

I was wondering what software I could use to produce graphs like this?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html), [IDL](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/PLOT3D.html), [Matplotlib in python](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), [Origin](https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Create-3D-Graph). I prefer matplotlib because it's free